# OpenCV 2.4.2 imshow causes crash

Tags: opencv

I have this nasty problem with opencv 2.4.2. 
I use VS 2012 to compile this short test programm.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat sudoku = imread("sudoku.jpg",0);
    namedWindow("Lines", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("Lines", sudoku);

}
```

Imshow is the problem. When I remove it, it runs without any problem. I found a tip here which said to use debug libs instead but it didn't help.

Comment: classical cause of imshow crashes are 1) image is not loaded properly, 2) opencv has been built without GUI support (GTK or Qt). Writting down your error message would help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you have to check if image is loaded correctly. To do this just check if `image.data` is `NULL` or not.

Secondly, after calling `imshow` you have to call `waitKey` to show image:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/user_interface.html#cv-waitkey

Here's the whole code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat sudoku = imread("sudoku.jpg",0);

    if (sudoku.data == NULL)
    {
        cout << "No image found! Check path." << endl;
        return 1;//ERROR
    }
    else
    {
        namedWindow("Lines", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Lines", sudoku);
        waitKey();//without this image won't be shown
        return 0;//OK
    }

}
```

Comment: stupid me.I put the picture in the wrong folder. So you are right that it wasn't loaded correctly. thank you.